# Return HTML content as a string, given URL. Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a javascript function that returns HTML content as string given URL to the function. I found a similar answer on Stackoverflow.

I am trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4033310/536890) to solve my problem.

However, it seems as though `document.write()` isn't writing anything. When I load the page, I get a a blank screen.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
  function httpGet(theUrl)
  {
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
  }
  document.write(httpGet("https://stackoverflow.com/"));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use .innerHTML, not document.write.

Comment: Do you mean like `httpGet("http://stackoverflow.com/").innerHTML;` ? This loaded a blank page as well.

Comment: The answers below describe what you need.

Comment: Chrome 77.0.3865.90, getting warning `(index):40 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you need to return when the readystate==4 e.g.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlhttp.send();    
}
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and the console error reads `Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlHttp is not defined `

Comment: Won't this cause a Same Origin Policy violation ? :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @SoboLAN Yes it does. (At least for me)

Comment: @Twitterhandlejasoki Perhaps you have 'use strict' on?

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false )` is not supported on the main thread. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321

Comment: @JasonKim, define it: let/var/const xmlhttp;

Answer (score 17):

The only one i have found for Cross-site, is this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var your_url = 'http://www.example.com';

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jquery.xdomainajax.js  ------ from padolsey

jQuery.ajax = (function(_ajax){

    var protocol = location.protocol,
        hostname = location.hostname,
        exRegex = RegExp(protocol + '//' + hostname),
        YQL = 'http' + (/^https/.test(protocol)?'s':'') + '://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?',
        query = 'select * from html where url="{URL}" and xpath="*"';

    function isExternal(url) {
        return !exRegex.test(url) && /:\/\//.test(url);
    }

    return function(o) {

        var url = o.url;

        if ( /get/i.test(o.type) && !/json/i.test(o.dataType) && isExternal(url) ) {

            // Manipulate options so that JSONP-x request is made to YQL

            o.url = YQL;
            o.dataType = 'json';

            o.data = {
                q: query.replace(
                    '{URL}',
                    url + (o.data ?
                        (/\?/.test(url) ? '&' : '?') + jQuery.param(o.data)
                    : '')
                ),
                format: 'xml'
            };

            // Since it's a JSONP request
            // complete === success
            if (!o.success && o.complete) {
                o.success = o.complete;
                delete o.complete;
            }

            o.success = (function(_success){
                return function(data) {

                    if (_success) {
                        // Fake XHR callback.
                        _success.call(this, {
                            responseText: data.results[0]
                                // YQL screws with <script>s
                                // Get rid of them
                                .replace(/<script[^>]+?\/>|<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/gi, '')
                        }, 'success');
                    }

                };
            })(o.success);

        }

        return _ajax.apply(this, arguments);

    };

})(jQuery.ajax);



$.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var text = res.responseText;
        // then you can manipulate your text as you wish
        alert(text);
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: I always get response text data results as 0 and throws exception.

Comment: Unfortunately, Yahoo APIs were shut down at March 2019 so this no longer works. :(

Answer (score 8):

after you get the response just do call this function to append data to your body element

```
function createDiv(responsetext)
{
    var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var _div = document.createElement('div');
    _div.innerHTML = responsetext;
    _body.appendChild(_div);
}
```

@satya code modified as below

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            createDiv(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
    xmlhttp.send();    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### You can't do this in the general case

...because of the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) that browsers use to restrict access to Site B from code running on Site A. When you try (with `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` etc.), you'll get an error saying something along the lines of:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

More in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i) and the SOP link above. But basically: It's not about preventing people seeing Site B's content, it's about not being able to do so from a context (a browser) that may have stored authentication information for the current user that would reveal their private information if you could read Site B's content from that user's browser.

A **very small number** of websites may serve their content using [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol) headers (the aforementioned `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and others) to allow any site to read their content, but that's very unusual.

If you want to retrieve the content of the vast majority of sites, you'll have to use code running in a non-browser context to do it (for instance, code running on a server somewhere). Over the years there have been many sites that allowed you to query them with a URL and return you the content of that URL queried by their server (and so not subject to the SOP, because the current user's browser-based authentication information for the other site isn't used), but they tend to spring up and then go away again as there's not really a good revenue model to support the bandwidth requirements. After all, why pay someone else for that when you can just run your own server for cheap (or even free) and do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of the accepted answer that 1) `returns` a value from the function (bugfix), and 2) doesn't break when using `"use strict";`

I use this code to pre-load a `.txt` file into my `<textarea>` when the user loads the page.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    let xmlhttp;
    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    
    return xmlhttp.response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some websites, `XMLHttpRequest` may send you something like `<script src="#"></srcipt>`. In that case, try using a HTML document like the script under:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="website.com"></iframe>
    <script src="your_JS"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now you can use JS to get some text out of the HTML, such as `getElementbyId`.

But this may not work for some websites with cross-domain blocking.