# load external page into a div with html or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

So, I have this code in index.html:

```
<td><a id="link" href="">Vídeos</a></td>
```

and then

```
<div name="content" id="content"></div>
```

I want to load a page named vid_content.html

I tried  a lot of code I found everywhere but nothing went right..

PS: all the pages are local in the same folder!

The last thing I tried was:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#link").click(function(){ 
        $("#content").load("vid_content.html");
    });
}
```

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function

Comment: This should be basic ajax.. what did you try?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, maybe an iframe is enough: `<iframe src="other_page.html"></iframe>`

Comment: @Jason P - The last think I tried was:

    $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#link").click(function(){
 $("#content").load("vid_content.html");
 });
}

This seems basic, but it won't work.

Comment: @Avitus, that doesn't work for me, because I don't want to get a url but an html file

Comment: That code looks correct. Are there any errors in your browser's javascript console? Everything look right on the network tab?

Comment: which directory is the html file in?

Comment: @Jason P: I have a warning saying: Invalid CSS rule at: <

Comment: @AlexShilman: jQuery is loaded and working. The file is in the same directory as the index.html

Comment: What about your network tab in the debugger, what does that say?

Comment: @jbarradas After you do the ajax, In the network tab of your debugger, you should see the status, if it's 200 or 404 or any. What does it say?

Comment: @AlexShilman how can I see that? I'm using chrome.

Comment: right-click > inspect element > network (tab)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 $('#content').load('/path/to/vid_content.html');
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention you need to be on at least a local server (appache with mamp or xamp). If not, you'll have an error.

Comment: @Seb server is not needed for the task

Comment: @Rohit Agrawal, there's browser restriction for ajax .load() with Chrome. Firefox seems to work tho.

Comment: Just for fun, try it in firefox. Just for the thrill.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make use of .html() within jQuery to define what the html contained within the div is.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("#link").click(function(){ 
        $("#content").html("vid_content.html");
      });
    }
```

Comment: what should i put in href="" ?

Comment: You shouldn't need anything there as you are not referencing another page. You are loading into the page you are currently on.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with the code. Firstly, the Ajax request won't work unless you're running this on a local server. Simply opening the HTML file in Chrome won't work. Secondly, you need to pass in the event object to the click handler so that you can stop the page reloading when you click on the link, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#link").click(function(e){ 
        $("#content").load("vid_content.html");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Lastly, you were missing the final closing bracket from the jQuery ready function.

Comment: what should I put in href of the #link ? I will put it online on a free domain to test it.

Comment: Just put a # for the href. It's not being used because the javascript is working instead. Alternatively you could make the href point to the `vid_content.html` file, and then the javascript can use the href for the Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Already got a solution!

Done it this way:

`function load_vids(){
         document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="vid_content.html #content" style="width:811px; height:570px"></object>';
        }`

And this:

`<td><a id="link" href="#" onclick="load_vids()">Videos</a></td>`

Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 0):

Save this into "firstpage.php".
with -> jQuery v2.2.3

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#content').load("secondPage.php", function() {
        //do something
    });

    $(document).on('click','#third',function(){
        $('#content').load("thirdPage.php", function() {
            //do something
        });
    });

});
```

Into secondPage.php

```
page 2<br>
----------------------<br>
<a href="#" id="third">load third</a>
```

Into thirdPage.php

```
hello world
```