# How to get content html from url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to get content html from url via javascript ?(not use ajax  or "load" method jquery because for security Access-Control-Allow-Origin ).

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no way to load content without using ajax.

Comment: oh,if I get content html from url via ajax,and have some url I get error "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".I try to fix but I can not fix

Comment: check this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function i think u need html content in string url