# How to get content from another website using JQ or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http-headers

How to get contents of another website, I mean from the entire HTML code just by using jQuery and Javascript and then parse that content parsing every tag and every attribute from the response. Any Answer must be appreciated.

Comment: 2 question are here, and both already answered many times   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax Else YQL might do the job.

Answer (score -1):

I guess u can achieve this using iframe or using jquery.load

Comment: Both are restricted to same origin policy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @rajkumar same origin policy only allows data sharing between two URL of same origin and ajax also do the same.

Comment: The question rises How Iframe fetch the webpage content.