# Only eval a specific js function in a string

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18447497/5494061) override to get the content of a js file as a string.

Content of the variable where the js file is loaded into:

```
<html>
<body>
//META{"name":"testPlugin"}*//
function testPlugin() {
    var settings = {
        testSettingBool : true,
        testSettingInt : 123,
        testSettingStr : "Test String",
    }
}
testPlugin.prototype.getName = function() { return "Test"; };
testPlugin.prototype.getDescription = function() { return "Test Description"; };
testPlugin.prototype.getVersion = function() { return "1.0"; };
</body>
</html>
```

Now i only want to eval a special function in that string like

```
testPlugin.prototype.getVersion();
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: "Content of the variable where the js file is loaded into".... I don't get that. So you're saying that first snippet is what's being eval'd?

Comment: that first snippet is the content of [this website](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Bluscream/BetterDiscord-Plugins-and-Themes/master/src/plugins/testPlugin.plugin.js) for example. And since the text formatting can always change there is no sense in using regex.

Comment: Okay, so your question is how to eval only part of a string?

Comment: I see no other way to get the version number from it, so yes.

Comment: You can't eval just part of the string

Comment: can i make it run in a different namespace then? so it doesn't register the functions in `window.*`?

Comment: you could run it in an iframe

Comment: So i create a iframe, eval the whole file in there, call the function in the iframe and then move it back to the top frame?

Comment: You could try that. eval'ing in the iframe will keep the code out of your window.* context.

Comment: sounds like a workaround, will try :D