# get Elements By Class Name from other page

Tags: javascript, console

I have this

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('value')[0].innerHTML);
```

Is there possibility to get this value from other page (without manually open this page)?

---

Can i get all value from page? Now when i use it i see only first value

Comment: There are few many ways, using localStorage, url-hash, server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there possibility to get this value from other page (without manually open this page)?

Without opening that page no, only from the current window (I assume this is what you mean when you're saying "page").

> Can i get all value from page? Now when i use it i see only first value

Yes, `document.getElementsByClassName('value')` returns an array i.e exactly what you need. In your example you're just selecting the first element from the array, that's why you see only the first value.

Try this:

```
var all=document.getElementsByClassName('value');

for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){
 console.log(all[i].innerHTML);
}
```

....

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

Create an AJAX request to get the website you need to extract values from. [This StackOverflow answer provides dependency-free example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10642376/2064544).

You can then parse the request using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), [which is supported by all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xml-serializer).

Answer (score 0):

Set your value to local storage :

Set value to local storage `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');`

Get value from another page `localStorage.getItem('key');`

**Set your data**

```
var data = document.getElementsByClassName('value')[0].innerHTML;
localStorage.setItem('value', data);
```

**Get it from another page**

```
localStorage.getItem('value');
```

***Documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage***

Otherwise you can use `sessionStorage`, `Web SQL`, `IndexedDB` & `Cookies`.

Comment: How exactly can you set a value to the local storage, without opening that page?

Comment: I am not advanced user. Can you  give me whole code?