# Get downloaded file content by code

Tags: javascript, html, file, download

The following url
https://planning.univ-st-etienne.fr/jsp/custom/modules/plannings/anonymous_cal.jsp?resources=3797&projectId=1&calType=ical&firstDate=2017-08-22&lastDate=2018-08-20
automatically downloads a file for me (.ics) which I need its text content. I would like to automatically get this text by code for my website so I don't need to update it manually everyday.

How could I manage that?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return HTML content as a string, given URL. Javascript Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use client-side language(`Javascript`), it will be so difficult [Follow question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function).

Then if you use server-side like PHP, you could code like this:

```
<?php
    $urlICS = 'https://planning.univ-st-etienne.fr/jsp/custom/modules/plannings/anonymous_cal.jsp?resources=3797&projectId=1&calType=ical&firstDate=2017-08-22&lastDate=2018-08-20';
    $contentICS = file_get_contents($urlICS);
    echo $contentICS;
?>
```