# oEmbed Instagram in Jekyll using Liquid (no custom plugins)

Tags: json, jekyll, instagram-api, liquid, oembed

I'm trying to embed Instagram posts into posts on my Jekyll site. I'm using the oEmbed method. The URL that Instagram documentation has, gives a JSON which contains a key-value pair for HTML which is what I want to extract.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Enter the shortcode for the image in a post frontmatter (`instagram: fA9uwTtkSN`)
2. Call an `include` that takes in the shortcode and makes an oEmbed call, to get to the JSON (`https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/{{ page.instagram }}/`)
3. Extract the value for the `HTML` key, and place it in the post.

I'm trying to write an `include` that does it, without the use of a [Ruby plugin](https://gist.github.com/vanto/1455726).

Pointers, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add the parameter to the post frontmatter `instagram: BbR55zEnaQL`
2. Call the include inside the post content:

   ```
   {% include insta.html id=page.instagram %}
   ```
3. Create the include file at `_includes/insta.html` with:

   ```
     <script>
      function httpGet(theUrl)
      {
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
          else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                  {
                      createDiv(xmlhttp.responseText);
                  }
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
          xmlhttp.send();    
      }

      function createDiv(responsetext)
      {
          var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
          var _div = document.createElement('div');
          _div.innerHTML = JSON.parse(responsetext)["html"];
          _body.appendChild(_div);
      }

      httpGet("https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/{{ include.id }}/");
     </script>
   ```

That will include the HTML blockquote returned by instagram at the bottom of the `body`.

## Notes

Javascript code is a modified version of [Return HTML content as a string, given URL. Javascript Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10642418/1165509)

Comment: Hey @marcanuy, I think I did not make much sense. What I get after implementing the suggested solution is [this](http://test.merakipost.com/2017/11/on-india). (The Instagram window appears at the bottom of the article, and does not contain the image for some reason.) What I'm looking for is [something like this](http://test.merakipost.com/2017/11/blowfish-by-siddharth-tripathi). Meanwhile, I also found http://sharedmemorydump.net/embedding-instagram-posts. I'll try tinkering with that as well.

Comment: Just change the placeholder for where the response will be injected. I've tested the code and works for me, it display the whole image.

Comment: That fixed it! I made some minor edit to the code, to load it `after` the paragraph preceding it. And added a class for formatting. The edit has been submitted. Thank you!

Comment: @RamIyer - I tried to use this code and I am not seeing the instagram post. Can you post your final working code?

Comment: I ended up greatly simplifying "insta.html" to ```  <iframe src="https://www.instagram.com/p/{{ include.id }}/embed" width="400" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: @jessi yeah, that iFrame would simply bring the image into the post. The reason I wanted to use an oEmbed was in order to have Instagram interactions like liking the picture within the post. However, I couldn’t implement a working solution across all browsers. I fell back to hotlinking from Instagram without iframe, simply using CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I took Marcanuy's answer and replaced insta.html with Instagram's own embed code. I pulled out their SVG logo into a separate file and moved the embed.js bit to the page I'm embedding to so it doesn't get called multiple times.

Also, since my requirement was to include multiple posts on a page, I did not put the post ID in front matter and instead put it in the include block itself.

`{% include insta.html id="BbR55zEnaQL" %}`

I talk about in detail here.

http://khoparzi.com/2019-02-06-embedding-instagram-on-jekyll/