# Diff2html diff not loading

Tags: javascript, html, diff, diff2html

I am using [diff2html](https://diff2html.xyz/) to show the diffs in a git PR in an HTML page. I have added the necessary scripts and is calling the object like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var diffHtml = Diff2Html.getPrettyHtml(
        'https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html/pull/106',
            {
                inputFormat: 'diff', 
                showFiles: true, 
                matching: 'lines', 
                outputFormat: 'side-by-side'
            }
        );
        document.getElementById("diff-container").innerHTML = diffHtml;
</script>
```

Now this is showing **Files changed (0)**. The URL I have given is the one given in the demo section of their website and have diff. I am doing this correctly ? Or how can I fetch from a the URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `getPrettyHtml` accepts a [diff string](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html#browser-library), not the link itself. There is no way to handle diff calculations with diff2html itself, this library only prettifies it. You can easily retrieve diff with this GitHub tip:

> Add .patch or .diff to the end of URLs for Git’s plaintext views.

To retrieve the data via URL you could take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function).

Comment: Is there any function to load the diff from URL ?

Comment: @HappyCoder I've added more information. Feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am trying to pull the `diff` using AJAX, but it is blocked by `CORS` policy. Is there anyway to get around this ?

Comment: @HappyCoder take a look at this discussion: https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/6ca596217c8dfba237744966c2b5ab1e

Answer (score 0):

A bit irrelevant but one can use [xdiff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php) ([PECL package](https://pecl.php.net/package/xdiff)) in PHP in order to produce unified model (ie. difference between string or file that is what the library likes) and supply that output to the [Diff2HtmlUI](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html#diff2htmlui-usage) to produce the nice Gitlab/Github diff based UI/UX.

That is how I did and its fantastically works:

```
Step 1: $string1 = 'contains from file-1/string1';
Step 2: $string2 = 'contains from file-2/string2';
Step 3: $getUnifiedDiff = xdiff_string_diff($string1, $string2);
Step 4: Initialise the configuration (as you've done above) and follow through 
var diff2htmlUi = new Diff2HtmlUI(targetElement, $getUnifiedDiff, configuration);
diff2htmlUi.draw();
diff2htmlUi.highlightCode();
```

~ All the best