# Can content from AWS Amplify Storage be downloaded directly into browser?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm working on a JS React app that stores and does transformations at the XML level on large SVGs(1-5MB) and can display the results in the browser.  I'm using AWS Amplify to handle the backend, but all documentation I have found is for displaying images in  tags via URI and nothing on loading S3 content into state, for example.

Is it possible to get bulk text directly from S3/Amplify Storage instead of having to go through the URI?
Is there a different AWS offering more applicable for this use-case?

EDIT1:
I've found another post that I think can help me solve my problem.  I'll post back with results.

[Return HTML content as a string, given URL. Javascript Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function#10642376)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to transform a URL into an URI.

```
function getDataUri(url, callback) {
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
        canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        // Get raw image data
        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));

        // ... or get as Data URI
        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    };

    image.src = url;
}

// Usage
getDataUri('/logo.png', function(dataUri) {
    // Do whatever you'd like with the Data URI!
            this.setState({
              fileUrl: dataUri
            })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gerard.  I'm not using canvas as it doesn't support some SVG feature I need currently.

Comment: Have you tried it? This is using canvas to capture the rendering in the Image element using the data Uri. As far as I know the rendering is handled by the Image element not the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the wrong question.  The Amplify Storage API can't give you the actual data, just a URL where you can get it.  I ended up crafting an XMLHttpRequest to get the data from the URL provided by Amplify Storage and doing my transforms on that.  Adding Promises to Christian Pietsch's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642289/return-html-content-as-a-string-given-url-javascript-function#10642376) solved my problem.

```
httpGet = async (theUrl: string) => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //not supporting IE 6 or below
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        resolve(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
  });
  const data = await promise;
  return data;
}
```